# How to load swf in Flex 4 and extract its contents (i.e movie clips etc)

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am working on Flex Project using Flash Builder 4. I want to load swf (that has been made using flash CS5 and it contains about 150 movieclips in library, nothing on stage). Now I want to load its Movie Clips in flex?

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the swf as a swc (checkbox option in the Publish Settings), and export the swc to the libs directory of your flex project.  Anything in the library that has been classes is automagically available to you flex app at that point.

Comment: Thanks @sberry2A.                                                     Can you give me an example or any link from where I can get an idea of doing so? Because I am new to Flex. And I need this as soon as possible.

Comment: I've exported .swc in library of lfex. now how to access that classes?

Comment: I added .swc in library and then made objects of movie clips. i.e        private var ltr101:letter101 = new letter101(); here letter101 is movie clip. It this mehod is correct? or there is another way? I've 150 movieclips, so I've to variablesa of each one? Please help me.